# searching for a dedicated binary linear programming algorithm

Tags: linear-programming

There are various linear programming solvers out there, among which lpSolve or GLPK. These are general LP solvers that are suitable for many purposes, but is there a dedicated LP solver for the binary case?

To exemplify, my problem involves finding the minimum number of lines that cover all columns of a matrix, something like:

```
0    1    0    1
1    0    0    1
1    0    1    0
```

It can be seen the first and third rows cover all four columns, the second row being irrelevant. Denoting the three lines as A, B and C, the problem boils down to solving a system of inequations:

```
B + C >= 1
A >= 1
C >= 1
A + B >= 1
```

This gives the solution:
A = 1; B = 0; C = 1

(which means the minimum number of lines is 2).

Thanks in advance,
Adrian

Comment: (1) This is a set covering problem. (2) Good MIP solvers do a very good job on this. (3) Glpk is not the most advanced MIP solver. Its performance does not always reflect what other solvers can achieve. (4) Approximation algorithms and heuristics exist for this problem.

Comment: Thank you Edwin, I am aware there are good MIP solvers that do a good job. lpSolve does it very well for instance, but they are also good at many other things, while I am mainly interested in a pure binary solver. Not sure if I need to use all code from lpSolve, or link to an(y) external library, just for this. Embedding a pure binary solver is what I am looking for.

Comment: LpSolve is not a state-of-the-art solver. Pure binary solvers are not widely available (most algorithms lend themselves to include handling of general integers). I am not sure if asking for a pure binary solver is very useful.

Comment: I think you want to minimize A+B+C? In addition to MIP, you might want to also look into MaxSAT solvers. They hold a yearly competition which will have a list of solvers and results. 2019: https://maxsat-evaluations.github.io/2019/tracks.html . These focus on binary variables and have very different heuristics than MIP solvers, which might or might not be better for the problem you are interested in.

Comment: Thanks Erwin and Tim, I understand. Will then look for the simplest most effective general integers solver, and the MaxSAT solvers look extremely interesting (did not know about this competition).